# What does [Max tasks per child setting] exactly mean in Celery?

Tags: python-3.x, celery

The doc is:

> With this option you can configure the maximum number of tasks a worker can execute before it’s replaced by a new process.

In what condition will a worker **be replaced by a new process** ? Does this setting make a worker, even with multi processes, can only process one task at one time?

Answer (score 11):

It means that when celery has executed tasks more than the limit on one worker (the "worker" is a process if you use the default process pool), it will restart the worker automatically.

Say if you use celery for database manipulation and you forget to close the database connection, the auto restart mechanism will help you close all pending connections.

Comment: what would be a reason why this is necessary?

Comment: @lollerskates "Say if you use celery for database manipulation and you forget to close the database connection, the auto restart mechanism will help you close all pending connections."

Comment: You can also run multiple celery instances where, for example, one instance handles only infrequent, but long-running tasks that end up allocating a large heap (not necessarily a leak). You may not want those processes to hang around taking up system memory when they're not doing any actual work.

Comment: But why does it restart in the middle of processing a "unit of work". In our case, when the restart happened, the unit of work was in the middle of execution. Is there a way by which the restart can be scheduled in such a way that its not executing any unit of work?

Comment: @bgth That's another question. You may refer https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#time-limits